# Peer is constantly lying ( or just confused about the current head)

Tags: go-ethereum, android

I think every one should have the right to disagree about the chain head - but he should not tell me all the time:

```
GoLog: I0305 11:44:49.604203 eth/downloader/downloader.go:640] Peer f61925002670fd0a [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss    0, rtt 20s]: lied about chain head: reported 597917, found above 598093
GoLog: I0305 11:45:33.469136 eth/downloader/downloader.go:640] Peer f61925002670fd0a [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss    0, rtt 20s]: lied about chain head: reported 597917, found above 598093
GoLog: I0305 11:45:52.695161 eth/downloader/downloader.go:640] Peer f61925002670fd0a [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss    0, rtt 20s]: lied about chain head: reported 597917, found above 598093
GoLog: I0305 11:46:38.834750 eth/downloader/downloader.go:640] Peer f61925002670fd0a [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss    0, rtt 20s]: lied about chain head: reported 597917, found above 598093
GoLog: I0305 11:47:00.482255 eth/downloader/downloader.go:640] Peer f61925002670fd0a [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss    0, rtt 20s]: lied about chain head: reported 597917, found above 598093
GoLog: I0305 11:47:25.917655 eth/downloader/downloader.go:640] Peer f61925002670fd0a [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss    0, rtt 20s]: lied about chain head: reported 597917, found above 598093
GoLog: I0305 11:47:58.996835 eth/downloader/downloader.go:640] Peer f61925002670fd0a [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss    0, rtt 20s]: lied about chain head: reported 597917, found above 598093
GoLog: I0305 11:48:29.059101 eth/downloader/downloader.go:640] Peer f61925002670fd0a [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss    0, rtt 20s]: lied about chain head: reported 597917, found above 598093
GoLog: I0305 11:48:59.110969 eth/downloader/downloader.go:640] Peer f61925002670fd0a [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss    0, rtt 20s]: lied about chain head: reported 597917, found above 598093
GoLog: I0305 11:49:54.924330 eth/downloader/downloader.go:640] Peer f61925002670fd0a [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss    0, rtt 20s]: lied about chain head: reported 597917, found above 598093
GoLog: I0305 11:50:01.418339 eth/downloader/downloader.go:640] Peer f61925002670fd0a [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss    0, rtt 20s]: lied about chain head: reported 597917, found above 598093
GoLog: I0305 11:51:07.694199 eth/downloader/downloader.go:640] Peer f61925002670fd0a [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss    0, rtt 20s]: lied about chain head: reported 597917, found above 598093
GoLog: I0305 11:51:09.246723 eth/downloader/downloader.go:640] Peer f61925002670fd0a [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss    0, rtt 20s]: lied about chain head: reported 597917, found above 598093
GoLog: I0305 11:51:44.009963 eth/downloader/downloader.go:640] Peer f61925002670fd0a [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss    0, rtt 20s]: lied about chain head: reported 597917, found above 598093
GoLog: I0305 11:52:14.168295 eth/downloader/downloader.go:640] Peer f61925002670fd0a [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss    0, rtt 20s]: lied about chain head: reported 597917, found above 598093
GoLog: I0305 11:52:44.232525 eth/downloader/downloader.go:640] Peer f61925002670fd0a [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss    0, rtt 20s]: lied about chain head: reported 597917, found above 598093
art: Thread[3,tid=5586,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0x74b5f0896400,peer=0x12c4c670,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
art: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
GoLog: I0305 11:53:22.698983 eth/downloader/downloader.go:640] Peer f61925002670fd0a [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss    0, rtt 20s]: lied about chain head: reported 597917, found above 598093
GoLog: I0305 11:54:07.755289 eth/downloader/downloader.go:640] Peer f61925002670fd0a [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss    0, rtt 20s]: lied about chain head: reported 597917, found above 598093
GoLog: I0305 11:54:31.084183 eth/downloader/downloader.go:640] Peer f61925002670fd0a [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss    0, rtt 20s]: lied about chain head: reported 597917, found above 598093
GoLog: I0305 11:55:10.613901 eth/downloader/downloader.go:640] Peer f61925002670fd0a [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss    0, rtt 20s]: lied about chain head: reported 597917, found above 598093
GoLog: I0305 11:55:41.619158 eth/downloader/downloader.go:640] Peer f61925002670fd0a [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss    0, rtt 20s]: lied about chain head: reported 597917, found above 598093
GoLog: I0305 11:55:57.562820 eth/downloader/downloader.go:640] Peer f61925002670fd0a [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss    0, rtt 20s]: lied about chain head: reported 597917, found above 598093
GoLog: I0305 11:56:47.485607 eth/downloader/downloader.go:640] Peer f61925002670fd0a [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss    0, rtt 20s]: lied about chain head: reported 597917, found above 598093
GoLog: I0305 11:57:17.427046 eth/downloader/downloader.go:640] Peer f61925002670fd0a [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss    0, rtt 20s]: lied about chain head: reported 597917, found above 598093
GoLog: I0305 11:57:52.725973 eth/downloader/downloader.go:640] Peer f61925002670fd0a [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss    0, rtt 20s]: lied about chain head: reported 597917, found above 598093
```

Is there a good way to deal with this? Perhaps block the peer? This is really hurting the sync-process ( look at the timestamps - really bad UX this way )

As it came up: Parity/Kovan are no option for me. Neither technically nor politically.

Comment: 13:20:51.390 and still getting no sync an the same message :-(

Comment: Is this the testnet or the main chain?

Comment: It is on ropsten

Comment: In that case, what you're seeing will be a consequence of the spam attacks that began in February, I'm afraid. I'll suggest that this question be duplicated to another thread concerning the attacks. That thread has some suggestions (i.e. use the new Kovan chain on Parity).

Comment: Hm thanks - but Parity/Kovan are no option for me. Neither technically nor politically. Also I do not think this is a duplicate question.

Comment: Then I'm afraid you'll have to wait for the Geth equivalent - Rinkeby - to be implemented. Until then you should consider using something other than the testnet for your testing.

Comment: Are you sure about this? It is always the same peer lying - why is blocking this peer not an option?

Comment: If that is the spamming peer, then blocking them would result in them creating another node and continuing the attack.

Comment: Ad infinitum. :-(

Comment: I would have no problem with him creating nodes ad infinitum - would always ignore them after they lied for some time. Would still work for me. Also as far as I understand the attack this node is not the attacker - but a symptom ( chain fork ) of this attack

Comment: The chain fork is likely a symptom of the attack, yes. Normally forks and  rearrangements would be fairly transient, but in this case there's significant hashing power behind it. The plan with Rinkeby is to move away from PoW completely.

Comment: Ropsten has been totally abandoned, I'm pretty certain it is easier to launch a fresh PoW-testnet rather than fixing Ropsten. However, with Kovan and Rinkeby it looks like the next generation of testnets will be PoA.

Comment: Yea but I think Rinkeby will take some time and I need one now. A private testnet is not an option as I need something that is understood by etherscan.io. Sad situation currently ..